# eBay timezone XML format - can somebody explain it?

Tags: timezone, iso8601

Can somebody explain the eBay timezone format for me for this two examples from GetItemTransactionsResponse?

```
<Timestamp>2015-01-28T14:33:17.884Z</Timestamp>

<ExternalTransactionTime>2015-02-01T10:52:53.000Z</ExternalTransactionTime>
```

What I don't get is the 884Z vs. the 000Z. Does that mean 4 hours and 0 hours offset relative to UTC? And if so, then what does the '88' stand for?

Answer (score 3):

Those are simply [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) / [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) formatted timestamps.  They are used all over the place - not just on eBay.

In the examples you provided, the period is separating seconds from fractional seconds, and the `Z` means the timestamp is in UTC.

```
2015-01-28T14:33:17.884Z = January 28th, 2015, 14 hours, 33 minutes, 17.884 seconds UTC

2015-02-01T10:52:53.000Z = February 1st, 2015, 10 hours, 52 minutes, 53.000 seconds UTC
```

Another way to think of it - since there are three decimal places, they represent milliseconds.  In other words, "17 seconds, 884 milliseconds".

Comment: Your answer explains it perfectly. Thank you!